# Modify date (month) in spark date column based on condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to modify my date column in spark df to subtract 1 month only if certain months appear. I.e. only if date is yyyy-07-31 or date is yyyy-04-30 change it to yyyy-06-31 and yyyy-03-30 respectively. Any ideas how to do it using pyspark functions?

```
|DateColumn|    
|2016-04-30|
|2015-04-30|
|2017-09-03|
|2017-07-31|
|2016-09-01|
|2018-07-31|
     ...
```

Expected outcome:

```
|DateColumn|    
|2016-03-30| <- changed
|2015-03-30| <- changed
|2017-09-03|
|2017-06-31| <- changed
|2016-09-01|
|2018-06-31| <- changed
     ...
```

Comment: similar to how @mckraqs positioned it, to make it more precise, you could also add a condition on the date along with the month condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the `functions` module and then combining several functionalities:

- `.when()` and then `otherwise()`
- `.month()`
- `.date_format()`
- `.add_months(date, -1)`

For example, it could come down to:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([{'date': '2022-04-15'}, {'date': '2022-05-17'}])

df \
    .withColumn('new_date', 
                F.when(F.month(F.col('date')).isin([4, 7]), 
                       F.add_months(F.date_format('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), -1))
                .otherwise(F.col('date'))) \
    .show()
```

and you would then get:

```
+----------+----------+
|      date|  new_date|
+----------+----------+
|2022-04-15|2022-03-15|
|2022-05-17|2022-05-17|
+----------+----------+
```

---

**Update** *(turned out it's rather substring problem than generic months subtracting, see comments for detail)*

Actually, you can stack `.when` functionality to do some sort of `if-elif-else` in Python. Below code shows how to perform it in the scenario you shared:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df \
    .withColumn('new_date', 
                 when(F.substring(F.col("date"), -5, 5) == '01-31', F.concat(F.year(F.col("date")), F.lit('-12-31')))
                .when(F.substring(F.col("date"), -5, 5) == '04-30', F.concat(F.year(F.col("date")), F.lit('-03-30')))
                .when(F.substring(F.col("date"), -5, 5) == '07-31', F.concat(F.year(F.col("date")), F.lit('-06-30')))
                .when(F.substring(F.col("date"), -5, 5) == '10-31', F.concat(F.year(F.col("date")), F.lit('-09-30')))
                .otherwise(F.col('date'))) \
    .show()
```

Comment: I am getting the belwo error when I try to run this code: ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Comment: It was rather a gist of what needs to be done, not the exact code that has to be executed. Anyway, I just modified the answer so it's working properly (at least on Spark 2.4.3) @cnns

Comment: Oh ok I didnt realize that. This works great. Let's say I also need to change days in similar fashion. Is there a way to combine another F.when to your code? Tried implementing that butkeep getting an error 'when() can only be applies on a column previosly generated by when() function'.

Comment: For example, after a month's subtracting you would also wish to have a condition that, e.g., if a day is 14th or 15th, go back by a week?

Comment: so it looks like my issue will come down to changing yyyy-01-31 to yyyy-12-31 and yyyy-04-30 to yyyy-03-31 and yyyy-07-31 to yyyy-06-30 and yyyy-10-31 to yyyy-09-30. The year should remain the same. It is only the months and days that should change following this pattern.

Comment: If that's the case, I would rather recommend working it out with substrings, as extra date parsing may require much more time to process. Just checking whether the last 5 characters are `04-30`, if so, then change them to `03-31`, and so on for all 4 cases you mentioned. `functions.substring()` will easily handle that. Do you need more help on the implementation?

Comment: I managed to come up with something like this which was actually more difficult than I anticipated. Is there a way to add another F.when statement to have all dates changed at once? df.withColumn('new_date', F.when(F.substring(F.col("date"), -5, 5) == '01-31', F.concat(F.year(F.col("date")), F.lit('-12-31')))))

Comment: Please see the answer update and tell me if that solves your issue. If so, you can upvote and accept the answer so the solution is visible to the rest of the community :)

Comment: I have spent like 30+ mins trying to do pretty much the same thing but using the below syntax which didn't work. Would you be able to explain why? Your solution works perfectly. Also BIG thank you - I can't emphasize how much I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df .withColumn('new_date', 
                 F,when(F.substring(F.col("date"), -5, 5) == '01-31', F.concat(F.year(F.col("date")), F.lit('-12-31')))
                .F.when(F.substring(F.col("date"), -5, 5) == '04-30', F.concat(F.year(F.col("date")), F.lit('-03-30')))
                .F.when(F.substring(F.col("date"), -5, 5) == '07-31', F.concat(F.year(F.col("date")), F.lit('-06-30')))
                .F.when(F.substring(F.col("date"), -5, 5) == '10-31', F.concat(F.year(F.col("date")), F.lit('-09-30'))).otherwise(F.col('date'))) .show()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244727/discussion-between-mckraqs-and-cnns).